# Angular PWA - How to force reload a new version

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

[Angular PWA] I'm using the below code to force reload a new version after I deploy. However, it not works, it still load old code. Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

After I deploy code to the server. At the client (browsers), I click on a button to call the below code.

```js
this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the complete code involved?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using --output-hashing while doing the build through angular cli, which will allow a clean refresh for all PWA apps too.

Check out https://angular.io/cli/build for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @maxkart. I have used the below command to execute "npm run buildProd".

In package.json file "buildProd": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --aot --outputHashing=all".

However, I still get old code after I deploy/

Comment: can you try "ng build --prod --output-hashing=all"

Comment: @ThanhVietNguyen, did you figure this out? I'm also using hashing and my app is not loading the new code using  location.reload()

Comment: same here not able to see the changes with `ng build && http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist` any suggestion please